# Pendulum on a moving cart that begins acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

I have a pendulum hanging on a cart that is travelling at constant velocity. The pendulum is oscillating about a fixed pivot. The initial movement of the pendulum can be represented by this equation:

$$ \theta(t)\; =\; \theta_{o}\:cos\:(\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}\:t) $$

This function will result in a cosine wave.

Is there a formula that allows me to plot the subsequent behaviour of the pendulum.

So far from my research, I have found out the formula that represents a stationary cart that begins acceleration.

$$ \theta(t)\; =\; \theta_{o}\:cos\:(\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}\:t)\: -\: tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{g})  $$
a : cart's acceleration

Since the pendulum is already swinging in the first scenario. If I know its $\theta$ and $\omega$ just before the cart begins to accelerate. Is it possible to incorporate these pieces of information to the above formula?

Comment: The first function is a solution for the small angles approximation. Doing the small angle approximation in the accelerating frame, I don't get $-\arctan(\frac{a}{g})$ but just $-\frac{a}{g}$. Where did that second function came from? Anyways, it only applies for a $\textbf{constant}$ acceleration. If $a=a(t)$ you won't get a priori a solution that can be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: To answer what I think is your question: $\textbf{Any}$ solution will have 2 constants (constants of integration) which won't be determined until you specify $\theta$ and $\omega$ (initial conditions). Those values will determine the values for $\theta_0$ and $\phi$. You didn't wrote the last one, but it should be inside the cosine as $\cos(\sqrt{\frac{q}{L}} t + \phi)$. Let me know if this answers your question so I can write a more clear answer.